# Membership credential verification failed and ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have a standard ASP.NET MVC 3 website. From a few days ago **some** uses cannot login or recover password anymore.

When trying to login they get the following error:

```
Login failed. Please correct the errors and try again. 
•The user name or password provided is incorrect.
```

When trying to recover password they get the following error:

```
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
```

In the web server event viewer we see:

```
Event code: 4006 
Event message: Membership credential verification failed. 
Event time: 4/29/2013 4:22:16 AM 
Event time (UTC): 4/29/2013 8:22:16 AM 
Event ID: 2b0b4500be674969a5962608df7b18fd 
Event sequence: 142 
Event occurrence: 2 
Event detail code: 0
```

If we try to register a new user afterward we can login and reset password without problems.

Why only **some** users get the issue above?

We checked many articles on the internet but explain only to solve this issue for all users, not only for some of them.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like the Machine key may have been changed.  Did you move the site to a different server?  Or did you add or change the Machine key setting?

Comment: No, we did some minor modifications to the website and nothing else. The web server simply gets MS updates regularly.

Comment: What sort of "minor modifications"?

Comment: Nothing related to user login, we added a controller, some actions & views, etc.

Comment: Have you diffed your current version with the older version in source control to see what changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason we where not getting the LockedOut exception but simply the "Invalid username or password" error. Now we will investigate on the reason.